# How To Cast Generic List of One Type To Generic List of an Unknown Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I would like to write a function that takes a `List<Object>` and returns a the original list casted to a list of a specified object type `List<ObjectType>`, knowing that the objects within the original list are of type `ObjectType`. The trick is that `ObjectType` could be any type, which I find using Reflection. Sorry for the lack of code, but I have had no luck understanding how I might even go about doing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you *know* that each item in the list is of type `ObjectType`, you can do this:

```
List<object> sourceList = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> resultList = sourceList.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

If you actually want to convert each item in the list in a generic way, the simplest way would be to do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConvertTo<T>(this IEnumerable items)
{
    return items.Cast<object>().Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)));
}
```

This would be implemented as an extension method, so you can write:

```
List<object> sourceList = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<string> resultList = sourceList.ConvertTo<string>().ToList();
```

If the target type isn't known at compile-time, you would indeed need to use reflection. Something like this would work:

```
class ListUtil
{
    public static List<T> ConvertToList<T>(this IEnumerable items)
    {
        // see method above
        return items.ConvertTo<T>().ToList();
    }

    public static IList ConvertToList(this IEnumerable items, Type targetType)
    {
        var method = typeof(ListUtil).GetMethod(
            "ConvertToList", 
            new[] { typeof(IEnumerable) });
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(targetType);
        return (IList)generic.Invoke(null, new[] { items });
    }
}
```

And now you can call it like:

```
List<object> sourceList = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3 };
IList resultList = ListUtil.ConvertToList(sourceList, typeof(string));
resultList.GetType(); // List<string>
```

Of course, you loose any compile-time type safety with this method.

Comment: Why not just `return items.Cast<T>().ToList();`?

Comment: @bmused That only works when the all objects are of a type `T`. It's basically a box / un-box. In my example using integers as input, `.Cast<string>` and `.Cast<double>` would fail.

Comment: If the type is only known at runtime above approach won't work

Comment: @BrokenGlass See my updated answer for a solution that work when the type is only known at run-time.

Comment: I was looking for the last option you gave me. Awesome answer! I presume I could do a similar (but perhaps more complex) version of this to convert Arrays or Dictionaries from one type to another?

Comment: @BradRoss Yes, you can. In general you can convert any generic method to a method like this using `MakeGenericMethod`. Often it's the easiest way to support type parameters passed in at run-time.